# CodeIgniter get_cookie / input->cookie not retrieving

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I am setting a cookie like so:

```
$cookie = array(
            'name'   => 'test',
            'value'  => 'test',
            'expire' => 86500,
            'domain' => '.iwantaspeaker.com',
            'path'   => '/'
            //'secure' => TRUE
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        var_dump($this->input->cookie('test', false));
```

Which returns `bool(false)`

I get absolutely no response. I have in the config:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "iwas_";
```

And the cookie is stored as `iwas_test`, so I have also tried `$this->input->cookie("iwas_test",true);` to no avail.

I can also see that the cookie is set in  chrome:

[image]

[Furthermore, I have also tried using the cookie helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html). What must I do to retrieve the cookie correctly? the URL is on a local network machine, so the domain is pointed to the local IP with an entry in my hosts file, if this makes any difference.

Comment: didn't you `echo` it ? `echo $this->input->cookie("test",true);`

Comment: @Dave yes, both with and without - the standard input class

Comment: ahh sorry i was mixed up on the question, does it work in any browsers or none

Comment: also, i see your setting it for a domain with the www. prefix, are you accessing the website that way also?

Comment: @Dave, have tried with and without (ie `'domain'=>'.iwantaspeaker.com'`) and also blank

Comment: @Dave, also not working in FF & IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah-ha! make sure you dont pass expire as a string

```
$cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'test',
                'value'  => 'test',
                'expire' => 86500, <--
                'domain' => 'www.iwantaspeaker.com',
                'path'   => '/',
                'secure' => TRUE <-- will only be set on https
            );
        //  $this->ci->db->insert("UserCookies", array("CookieUserEmail"=>$userEmail, "CookieRandom"=>$randomString));
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

  var_dump($this->input->cookie('iwas_test', false));
```

Comment: also try a var_dump($this->input->cookie('test', false));

Comment: still no luck :( the var_dump returns -> `bool(false)`

Comment: See the updated code block in the question to see my full query now

Comment: can you try this?

$this->load->helper('cookie');     
      $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'test',
        'value'  => '23',
        'expire' =>  86500
      );
      $this->input->set_cookie($cookie); 
      var_dump($this->input->cookie('test', false));

Comment: my thought is it has something to do with the www. prefix or the SSL

Comment: So I tried: `$this -> load -> helper('cookie');
  $cookie = array('name' => 'test2', 'value' => '23', 'expire' => 86500);
  $this -> input -> set_cookie($cookie);
  var_dump($this ->input -> cookie('test2', false));` 

(Changed it to test2 to prevent conflict) yet still get `bool(false)`.

Comment: and in your config file what do the 4 cookie lines look like?
cookie_prefix,cookie_domain,cookie_path,cookie_secure

Comment: and if you remove the path, and set the secure to false, does that change it at all?

Comment: So just realised because of the prefix, i had to do `input->cookie('iwas_test2', false)` and I got the data. So  I think it was a combination of everything, all works well now, thanks very much Dave!